# how to add box-shadow or recreate the same as in given picture using css?

Tags: html, css

i want to createa  dialog like in below picture

[image]

the line marked in red should also be similar to the first line in dialog. they should have value like below,

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #00000029;
```

my code is like below and adding box-shadow to container_one div adds box shadow to all sides instead of adding to the bottom and hence it makes it thick on all three sides except bottom as wrapper also has box-shadow.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container_one"> //this needs box-shadow bottom
        <span class="text">sometext</span>
        <div class="description">some big description</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container_two"> //this needs box-shadow bottom
    </div>

</div>

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 32px;
    width: 316px;
    height: 225px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
    border-radius: 16px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    opacity: 1;
}

.container_one {
    height: 101px;
    width: 316px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-left: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px 16px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29); //this adds boxshadow to all sides   
}

.description {
     height: 42px;
     width: 289px;
     margin-top: 8px;
     color: black;
     display: flex;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: 400;
     margin-bottom: 16px;
 `; 

  .container_two {
      padding: 16px 0 16px 16px;
      height: 108px;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: no-wrap;
      overflow-y: hidden; 
  }
```

i want to add box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #00000029; to both container_one and container_two to get lines like in picture.

if not box-shadow what i can i do to get the lines like the first one after somedescription text using css???

could someone help me with this.
thanks.

Comment: I don't understand that arrow.

Comment: i added that arrow to say that it should be similar to the line just below some description text.

Comment: I'm confused too. Is the shadow meant to act like a divider so to speak? If so, remove the height from ``.container_two`` or adjust it...

Comment: @Dexterians: yes shadow meant to act like a divider. how can i add one like a divider?

Comment: i have edited the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comments in your original question, the height being set on `.container_two` is affecting your result. You also did not apply any `box-shadow` to it.

Change your `box-shadow` property to something like;

```
box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
```

on both your `.container_one` and `.container_two`.

Here is my snippet on how you can achieve a bottom shadow, but note that it affects its sides as we have to change the position of the shadow so that they don't overlap;

```css
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 32px;
    width: 316px;
    height: 225px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
    border-radius: 16px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    opacity: 1;
}

.container_one {
    height: 101px;
    /*width: 316px;*/    /*//removed width//*/
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-left: 22px;    /*//added 6px//*/
    padding-right: 6px;    /*//added 6px//*/
    border-radius: 16px 16px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
    margin: 0px -6px 0px -6px; /*this offsets the box to increase the shadow*/   
}

.description {
     height: 42px;
     width: 289px;
     margin-top: 8px;
     color: black;
     display: flex;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: 400;
     margin-bottom: 16px;
}

  .container_two {
      padding: 16px 6px 16px 22px; /*//added 6px on certain values//*/
      /*height: 108px;*/   /*//removed height//*/
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: no-wrap;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
      margin: 0px -6px 0px -6px; /*this offsets the box to increase the shadow*/
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container_one"> //this needs box-shadow bottom
        <span class="text">sometext</span>
        <div class="description">some big description</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container_two"> //this needs box-shadow bottom
    </div>

</div>
```

Just adjust the properties as you see fit.

**EDIT:** I've also adjusted the padding (increased by `6px` (16+6=22) on certain values so that it keeps text in box rather than going outside the box (inspect the element to understand more) as we've had to counter the negative margins and push them back in with padding).

Comment: thanks. can we get the box shadow to be of exact width as the wrapper div. right now it seems like cut on the sides?

Comment: oh okay. could you show me how that could be done with the wrapper div. thanks.

Comment: Check my edit. You will see I've put negative margins on ``.container_one`` and ``.container_two`` to offset the dimensions to increase the spread of the shadow. Adjust those values as you see fit.